# How to use array push method with $or and multiple $in in NodeJS and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have implemented a system in which the registered user can have friends and follow those that he/she don't want to be friends with.
From that, I implemented a system to fetch the posts from those users. Now, I would like to fetch the posts by the loggedIn user as well along with the other posts(by friends and users - loggedIn - user follows).

In order to that, I have to add the `req.user._id` which is the Id of the loggedIn user.

`following` and `friends` are arrays of objects containing the id from the users.

As of now the only way to make the fetching of both following and friends posts is by commenting the lines in which I'm trying to do the pushes?

Now the only way to fetch the loggedIn user posts is by fetching them along just one, the following user posts or the friends user posts... I want to fetch them together with both arrays.

Did I explain myself? Thanks in advance.

```
  const { following, friends } = req.user;
  // Include currentLoggedIn user posts
  following.push(req.user._id);
  friends.push(req.user._id);

  // Fetch posts by  both users I follow and users I'm friends with
  const posts = await Post.find({
    $or: [{ user: { $in: [following, friends] } }]
  })
    .populate({ path: 'user', select: 'username avatar bio' })
    .sort('-date')
    .skip(startIndex)
    .limit(limit);
```

Hopefully I could explain myself. This is the code it currently throws me:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "error": {
        "stringValue": "\"[ 5e0d1b9315a8f23df855e4c3, 5e0925629648903308163aeb ]\"",
        "kind": "ObjectId",
        "value": [
            "5e0d1b9315a8f23df855e4c3",
            "5e0925629648903308163aeb"
        ],
        "path": "user",
        "reason": {},
        "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[ 5e0d1b9315a8f23df855e4c3, 5e0925629648903308163aeb ]\" at path \"user\" for model \"Post\"",
        "name": "CastError",
        "statusCode": 500,
        "status": "error"
    },
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[ 5e0d1b9315a8f23df855e4c3, 5e0925629648903308163aeb ]\" at path \"user\" for model \"Post\"",
    "stack": "CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[ 5e0d1b9315a8f23df855e4c3, 5e0925629648903308163aeb ]\" at path \"user\" for model \"Post\"\n    at new CastError (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myporn\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\error\\cast.js:39:11)\n    at ObjectId.cast (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myporn\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\schema\\objectid.js:246:11)\n    at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myporn\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\schematype.js:975:12)\n    at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myporn\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\schematype.js:1389:15)\n    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myporn\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\schematype.js:1379:15)\n    at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myporn\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\schematype.js:1328:18\n    at Array.map (<anonymous>)\n    at ObjectId.handle$in (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myporn\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\schematype.js:1324:14)\n    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myporn\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\schematype.js:1376:20)\n    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myporn\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\schematype.js:1353:17)\n    at cast (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myporn\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\cast.js:296:39)\n    at cast (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myporn\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\cast.js:58:18)\n    at model.Query.Query.cast (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myporn\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\query.js:4683:12)\n    at model.Query.Query._castConditions (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myporn\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\query.js:1861:10)\n    at model.Query.<anonymous> (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myporn\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\query.js:1888:8)\n    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _find] (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myporn\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\helpers\\query\\wrapThunk.js:16:8)\n    at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myporn\\node_modules\\kareem\\index.js:278:20\n    at _next (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myporn\\node_modules\\kareem\\index.js:102:16)\n    at process.nextTick (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myporn\\node_modules\\kareem\\index.js:507:38)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)"
}
```

Which means (for what I know) that `req.user._id` could not be converted to the MongoDB `ObjectId` data type but then I tried requiring mongodb in my file to be able to use ObjectId but it keeps throwing me the same error.

Thanks!.

Comment: when using JSON, you can pass an ObjectId value in a query like `{"$oid":"5e0d1b9315a8f23df855e4c3"}`, have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, I tried it already and did not work :/

Comment: @Kirasiris : What does `req.user` ? why are you pushing `req.user._id` to both arrays ? You need to cast each element in array to objectid

Comment: you are casting an array of objectid to an objectid? `"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[ 5e0d1b9315a8f23df855e4c3, 5e0925629648903308163aeb ]\" at path \"user\" for model \"Post\""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this, assuming all inputs in general are strings & needs to be converted to `ObjectId()` before querying, if your **user** field is type `ObjectId()`, your issue seems to be looking for `ObjectId()` *Vs* what you're passing is an array of arrays, Also you don't need `$or` as there is only one condition, if you're mentioning two or more then use `$or` :

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

const { following, friends } = req.user;

// Include currentLoggedIn user posts
let mergedArray = [...following, ...friends];
mergedArray.push(req.user._id)
let usersArray = []
for (const i of mergedArray) {
    usersArray.push(new ObjectId(i))
}

// Fetch posts by  both users I follow and users I'm friends with
const posts = await Post.find({ user: { $in: usersArray } })
    .populate({ path: 'user', select: 'username avatar bio' })
    .sort('-date')
    .skip(startIndex)
    .limit(limit);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed!. I just had to edit yours a bit since I did not want to include looping through them. What I did was just `const mergedArray = [...following, ...friends]`;` and `mergedArray.push(req.user._id);`

Comment: pretty much what you suggested but without the for loop.

Comment: @Kirasiris : for loop is to convert string to ObjectId, it’s based on data so optional, just mentioned it..anyway cool.